# UML Class Models Needed for research

Tags: class, uml, models

I am doing research on UML class models. While pursuing that I need sample UML class models (preferably realistic and industry size).While searching on Internet, I do not came across any standard repository of class models. Kindly help me in getting such UML class models for my research work ?

Comment: There will not be any 'repository' like thing for classes. you try to install eclipse that is integrated with uml tools, and import java core standard source, and try to make a uml diagram of some package or class. day by day you will get what you want. To my knowledge, there is no public repository for classes that have UML modeled.

Comment: Thanks a lot sivatumma. I did the same using MagicDraw. But I have to analyze the actual UML class models which are created during forward engineering to give inputs to the software developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can see many diagrams simply searching for their names (class diagram, for example), in the Google search for pictures.

Also you can find many of them searching for different OOP patterns.

Many big and correct diagrams you can find in the UML standards - they use UML diagrams for defining UML diagram elements.